# Undefined reference usb_init()

Tags: c, linux, usb, libusb-1.0

I am working on customized USB driver for keyboard using libusb. I wrote a simple program and tried to compile that program i received warning and output file is not generated.

This is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

void main(){
  usb_init(NULL);
    return;
}
```

The error message is

```
sample.c: In function ‘main’:
sample.c:7:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_init’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   usb_init(NULL);
   ^
/tmp/ccYbyFAK.o: In function `main':
sample.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `usb_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I run this commands to set the library lining flag, commands are successfully executed.

```
pkg-config --list-all
pkg-config --libs libusb
```

i tried following commands to execute my prog

```
gcc -o output sample.c -lusb-1.0
gcc -o output sample.c -libusb-1.0
```

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Where is libusb located? Where did you get libusb? Was it distro installed? Can you provide install instructions or a download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the header file for libusb 1.0, but you are using `usb_init`, a function that is *not* part of it's API.  Note that libusb 0.1 is really old and has a different API than libusb 1.0.  You should refer to the documentation of libusb 1.0 to learn what functions are supported in libusb 1.0:

https://libusb.info/